# Jenkins pipeline with Copy Artifact Plugin to copy artifact from last complete build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifacts

In declarative Jenkins pipeline, we could copy artifacts from last complete build of a project with below codes:

```
            def lastBuildId = currentBuild?.getPreviousBuild()?.getId()
            copyArtifacts(projectName: "${JOB_NAME}", 
            selector: specific("${lastBuildId}")
            )
```

But in plugin instruction, I noticed one of selectors is "lastCompletedLast". but I don't know what is the correct usage of those selectors. It is wrong if I use:

```
                copyArtifacts(projectName: "${JOB_NAME}", 
                selector: lastCompletedLast())
                )
```

Is there any documentation?

Comment: Here is the link of this plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact). But I didn't find the usage of this selector in jenkins file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Snippet Generator (use the Pipeline Syntax link on any Pipeline job) is a good way to find these sorts of things. You fill in the UI, it generates the groovy code.

According to the generator, the following should work:

`copyArtifacts projectName: "${JOB_NAME}", selector: lastCompleted()`

**EDIT**: I originally added the last successful build selector, not per the OP request.  Fixed to be lastCompleted()

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the build I need is not "last successful build" but "last complete build(ignore its status)".

Comment: Oh, I see. It is: copyArtifacts projectName: "${JOB_NAME}", selector:  lastCompleted()

Comment: I can't take last (completed, successful or last with artifacts) because of multiple instances of the current job trigger different downstream jobs (e.g. with different parameters). How can I figure out the proper selector?

Comment: I receive error: failed to copy artifacts from ... with filter: **